# Downloading game memoryp roblem

Tags: applications

So I went to download a large game (1GB). It started downloading, and at 96% it stopped and said I don't have enough memory.

I wont try to download it again, but that 96% that I downloaded is still in my phone and I cant delete it. Can someone tell me how?

I went into options then applications, but there is no that game that I can delete. I tried to find it many times but it is not there.

Comment: How are you downloading this game? Is it an app in Google Play? Is it a file you downloaded from the browser? Which browser?

Answer (score 1):

If the download failed, the broken download was deleted.  It's not stored anywhere, and it's not taking up space.